# Sever can't git pull but I can

Tags: php, git, apache, github

I'm trying to use a post-receive hook to update a remote server. I'm using ssh and everything works great (running `git pull` does indeed pull). I've started with [this deploy.php](https://gist.github.com/1809044#file_deploy.php) and the other commands, like `git status`, do run and output as expected, but the pull doesn't appear to do anything at all.

I've `chown`ed the hell out of everything (the git repo, known_hosts, etc...), so my www-data user should be able to access just about anything on the sever. Is there any way I can at least find some error logging for what's going wrong?

**edit**: I don't see any change in the output after changing `git pull` to `git pull --verbose` as suggested by adder. The output is still:

```
$ whoami
www-data
$ git pull --verbose

$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   deploy.php
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

**Solution:** the apache user needs to be setup to ssh to github. I was connecting as root then getting confused when my post-receive hook target couldn't make the same update. I was doing it as root, the script was running as www-data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git help pull

```
--verbose 
Pass --verbose to git-fetch and git-merge.
```

Comment: Ty for the response adder, please see my edit, is that what you meant? If so it hasn't seemed to change the output when deploy.php is hit manually.

Comment: It turns out that when "I" was running `git pull` it was as root but I needed to `su www-data` in order to properly setup for the apache user to make the connection. `--verbose` is nice to now get more feedback (eg: Already up-to-date.).